# Sharing PKCanvasView with a subview as an Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `PKCanvasView` with a subview of a `UIImageView`.

I'd like to share the view as a `UIImage`. This would be the `UIImageView` with the `PKCanvasView.drawing` that is above it.

Here is how I am getting the drawing portion. I am just unsure how to get the `UIImageView` with it.

```
private func image(from canvas: PKCanvasView) -> UIImage {
    let drawing = canvas.drawing
    let visibleRect = canvas.bounds
    let image = drawing.image(from: visibleRect, scale: UIScreen.main.scale)
    return image
}
```

Update:

Here is what I am currently trying:

```
let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
format.opaque = false
let visibleRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.imageView.frame.size.width, height: self.imageView.frame.size.height)

let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.imageView.frame.size, format: format).image { context in
    imageView.image?.draw(in: visibleRect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
    canvasView.drawing.image(from: visibleRect, scale: UIScreen.main.scale).draw(at: .zero)
}
```

The problem I am facing with this is my image is being stretched from top to bottom. Some images more than others.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new graphics context, draw your image into it and then draw your drawing on top of it. Your code should look something like this:

```
let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
format.opaque = false
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageView.frame.size, format: format).image { context in
    imageView.image?.draw(at: .zero)
    canvas.drawing.image(from: imageView.frame, scale: UIScreen.main.scale).draw(at: .zero)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. This is close. The issue I am facing with this is the image is larger than expected so the image & the drawing/coloring over it doesn't line up.

Comment: @LukeIrvin you should create your canvas size based on the image size

Comment: Of course, definitely will. Just trying to get my image to look right at export. Then I can update the canvas size to match the image size.

Comment: You have to set the canvas before anything else. When setting up your CanvasViewControler  `canvasView.frame = view.frame` and  `canvasView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size`